# Why are we adding 0 to a double void pointer here?

Tags: c++, pointers, embedded, program-counter, stack-pointer

For context, this is code called from a bootloader that is supposed to boot into the main application. This snippet is from a function with an argument `uintptr_t address` that specifies the address of where the main application has been written to. I believe `sp` and `pc` are the stack pointer and program counter respectively.

Here's the code:

```
sp = *((void **)address + 0);
pc = *((void **)address + 1);
start_new_application(sp, pc);
```

Full context [here](https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbed-os/blob/e901dfad05a1471e3d5a2eaff2ac45ca02e1533d/platform/mbed_application.c)

And then I've gone and printed the address, sp, and pc, and found the following:

```
address -> 0x08010000
sp ------> 0x20050000
pc ------> 0x080132DD
```

This has me very confused. I'm not sure why the `sp` line has a `+ 0` in it at all. Could that `sp` line be rewritten as:

```
sp = (void *)address;
```

and do the same thing?

My understanding is that the address has been static_casted into a double void pointer and then `sp` is given the dereferenced value of address (0x08010000) and `pc` has been given the dereferenced value of the address (0x08010001). Then, in my printf statements these values displayed are the dereferenced values of *those* addresses.

Is my understanding correct here?

Comment: Redundant; Put there for alignment/pretty print purposes?

Comment: `address` probably contains the address of an array of pointers. Don't do this with an `int`, by the way. They aren't always the same size as a pointer. These days often an `int` is 32 bit and a pointer is 64. Use an `intptr_t` for stuff like this.

Comment: @user4581301 : address is an uintptr_t as can be seen on the full context code. See the github link.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `+ 0` is there merely for readability.

```
sp = *((void **)address + 0);
pc = *((void **)address + 1);
```

does the same as

```
sp = *((void **)address);
pc = *((void **)address + 1);
```

or using C++ casts and the subscript operator:

```
sp = reinterpret_cast<void**>(address)[0];
pc = reinterpret_cast<void**>(address)[1];
```

> Could that `sp` line be rewritten as:
>
> `sp = (void *)address;`

No, that would make `sp` equal to `address` which is not what the original code does. The orignal code extracts a `void*` from the address pointed to: `*address`.